# Navbar does not collapse when resizing window

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

There are few questions on Stack Overflow that are in regard to problems with the navbar collapse function. I did look at them, but none of them provided a solution to the problem I'm having.

I have a login form in my navbar, and when I resize my window the login stays "open," rather than collapsing like it should. When I click the menu button nothing happens. I'm not sure if it's an issue with "data-toggle," or "navbar-collapse," or both.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<title>Journal</title>
<!-- Bootstrap -->
<!--
<link href="css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
-->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css">
</head>
<body data-spy="scroll" data-target=".navbar-collapse">
  <div class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-top">
    <div class="container">
      <div class="navbar-header">
        <button class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-collapse">
          <span class="icon-bar"></span>
          <span class="icon-bar"></span>
          <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        </button>
        <a class="navbar-brand">Journal</a>
      </div>
    <div data-toggle="collapse navbar-collapse">
      <form class="navbar-form navbar-right" method="post"> 
        <div class="form-group">
          <input type="email" name="loginemail" placeholder="Email" class="form-control" value="<?php echo addslashes($_POST['loginemail']); ?>" />                                                        
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
          <input type="password" name="loginpassword" placeholder="Password" class="form-control" value="<?php echo addslashes($_POST['loginpassword']); ?>" />                                                                 
        </div>
          <input type="submit" name= "submit" class="btn btn-success" value="Log In">
      </form>
    </div>
  </div>    
</div>
<!--
<script src="js/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
-->
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: I don't see anything with the class `navbar-collapse`?

Comment: Oh my gosh. I can't believe that. Ha! Thank you so much. I needed to change "data-toggle" to "class." Silly mistake. It works now!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have kept `data-toggle` instead of `class` for `div`. Change it as below:

```
<div class="collapse navbar-collapse">
    <form class="navbar-form navbar-right" method="post"> 
    .....
    </form>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you! Yes, that was the problem. I can't believe I missed that.

Comment: Anytime.. It happens.. Happy coding..